# Wordpress Numeric Pagination with Query String

Tags: categories, wp-query, loop, pagination, query-string

So I have a dynamic loop which is affected by a query sting in the URL..

For example I have 3 categories and when they click the category it just adds a query to the URL:

```
<a href="?view=dogs">Dogs</a>
<a href="?view=cats">Cats</a>
<a href="?view=other">Other</a>
```

and then my custom loop will pull the query values to show relative posts

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'animals', 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'category' => $queryString);
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

I then have my pagination code which is working as expected but it doesn't change the posts.. I have a feeling its because of the url structure.. http://example.com/animals/page/2/?view=cats

any help from you awesome people!

Comment: You already have query vars(they're just masked by the pretty URL), use `&` in place of `?` ..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the paged variable isn't being added to the query arguments. This should work:

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'animals', 
    'posts_per_page' => 4, 
    'category' => $queryString,
    'paged' => $paged
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Also, as a note, `$wp_query` is a WordPress global variable. It would be safer to use a different name like `$my_query`, `$custom_query`, `$steve`, etc.

Comment: This has solved my problem! Thank you! Such a simple thing I missed!